# Virtual Private Database policy predicate has error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, predicate, policy

I'm trying to implement a vpd. So far I have created a function:

```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sales_select(
    schema_var IN VARCHAR2,
    table_var IN VARCHAR2
  )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
   return_val VARCHAR2(400);
  BEGIN
   return_val := 'time_id >= "01-JAN-01"';
  RETURN return_val;
  END sales_select;
  /
```

and the policy I made is the following:

```
L> BEGIN
2   DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
3    object_schema    => 'sh',
4    object_name      => 'costs1',
5    policy_name      => 'costs_policy',
6    function_schema  => 'policy_admin',
7    policy_function  => 'sales_select',
8    statement_types  => 'select'
9  );
0  END;
1  /
```

when I run the follow query:

```
select * from sh.costs1;
```

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-28113: policy predicate has error
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the quotes in the function but when I try changing them I get compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `time_id` a date column? If so, try changing line 9 to:

```
return_val := 'time_id >= date ''2001-01-01''';
```

Note the double quotes.

Comment: time_id is a date column, with the following format: DD-MON-YY